The purpose of Enigma plugboard
It is well known the number of Enigma combinations with plugboard:
$${5!\over(5-3)!}\cdot26^3\cdot{26!\over(26-20)!\cdot2^{10}\cdot10!}=158,962,555,217,826,360,000$$.
So, $(26-20)!\cdot2^{10}\cdot10!$ just decreases the overall number of combinations. Indeed, the commercial machine was not supplied with the board. On the other hand, the military version had the board to mix the electrical circuits with less level of combinations. I guess to prevent it's easy breaking.
My questions is about pros and cons of the switch board.
Do we want to increase the number of combinations  and the strength of the code at the same time and how no board situation affects the breaking the code?
Thank you for the explanations or estimations.

Hi!  If you don’t get a useful answer here you might try asking at https://crypto.stackexchange.com/
